# How can I create an inline function in scala that respects implicit conversions?

Tags: scala, generics, type-inference, implicit-conversion, implicit

Take the following code as an example:

```scala
object Test6 {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val a = new A
    //works
    takesBTuple(tupleMaker(a, a))
    //does not work, because a becomes an instance of ArrowAssoc[A] instead of ArrowAssoc[B]
    takesBTuple(a->a)
  }

  class A

  class B

  implicit def atob(a: A): B = new B

  def tupleMaker[X, Y](x: X, y: Y): (X, Y) = (x, y)

  def takesBTuple(b: (B, B)): Unit = println("taken")
}
```

How can I get the behavior of TupleMaker (specially w.r.t. implicit conversions), but with an inline function? I can modify both class A and B, and use any infix operator (doesn't have to be an existing one) if that helps the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add one more conversion

```
implicit def tupleToTuple(a: (A, A)): (B, B) = (atob(a._1), atob(a._2))
```

More generic solution is

```
class A
class A1
class B

implicit def atob(a: A): B = new B
implicit def a1tob(a: A1): B = new B

implicit def tupleToTuple[T, X1, Y1, X, Y](t: (X, Y))(implicit 
  ev: T <:< (X1, Y1), 
  ev1: X => X1, 
  ev2: Y => Y1
): T = (t._1, t._2)


val a = new A
val a1 = new A1

takesBTuple(a -> a) // compiles
takesBTuple(a1 -> a1) // compiles
takesBTuple(a -> a1) // compiles
```

Simpler

```
implicit def tupleToTuple[X, Y, X1, Y1](t: (X, Y))(implicit 
  ev1: X => X1, 
  ev2: Y => Y1
): (X1, Y1) = (t._1, t._2)
```

doesn't work because `X` is inferred first (to be `A`). So `ev: T <:< (X1, Y1)` is a trick to make `X1`, `Y1` be inferred first (to be `B`). Implicits are resolved from the left to the right.

Comment: I could define this implicit. However, let's assume there are multiple possible A classes that have implicit conversions to B. In order for this to work, the relevant implicit conversion would have to be in scope. However, since they are tuples, these implicit conversions would have to defined in the tuple class that I cannot modify. Let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: @GUIpsp *"these implicit conversions would have to defined in the tuple class"* No. You can import them to the current scope. https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html#where-do-implicits-come-from

Comment: While that is true, if there are multiple A classes, I'd either have to import each conversion separately, or bundle them all together and import them all at once. The first is unacceptable due to it being too verbose. The second is unacceptable in my case due to the classes being automatically generated: I can modify the generation, but I cannot create an index of them. This reply was written before the update

Comment: The updated solution seems to work, thanks. However, I'm trying to comprehend exactly how it works: I get that the ev1 ev2 parameters are automatically filled with the respective implicit functions, however, what is the role of the ev parameter?

Comment: @GUIpsp Well, the thing is that easier `implicit def tupleToTuple[X, Y, X1, Y1](t: (X, Y))(implicit ev1: X => X1, ev2: Y => Y1): (X1, Y1) = (t._1, t._2)` doesn't work because `X` is inferred first (to be `A`). So `ev: T <:< (X1, Y1)` is a trick to make `X1`, `Y1` be inferred first (to be `B`). Implicits are resolved from the left to the right.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to fix that would be

```
takesBTuple((a:B) -> a)
```

Otherwise, you can define a trait `ConvertibleToB` that has `->` as a method, and then this would work.

```
val a = new A
val aa = new AA
//all of these work
takesBTuple(tupleMaker(a, a))
takesBTuple(a -> a)
takesBTuple(aa -> a)
takesBTuple(a -> aa)
takesConvertibleToBTuple(a -> a)
takesConvertibleToBTuple(a -> aa)

//Just for demonstration
def takesConvertibleToBTuple(t: (ConvertibleToB, ConvertibleToB)): Unit = println("took " + t)
```

```
trait ConvertibleToB {
  def convertToB: B
  def ->(b: B): (B, B) = (convertToB, b)
  def ->(a: this.type): (this.type, this.type) = (this, a)
}

class A extends ConvertibleToB {
  override def convertToB: B = new B
}

class AA extends ConvertibleToB {
  override def convertToB: B = new B
}

implicit def makeB(c: ConvertibleToB): B = c.convertToB
```

The only implicit def you need to import is `makeB`. I don't know if this is what you want or if it will be practical for you, though, especially if you don't want tuples of type `(A, AA)` to be converted to `(B, B)`

Link to Scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/pPuzw0sSQfKlglfT0a3Rrw